# Нужна помощь с настройкой Eclips для app engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

Есть проект, нужна помощь в открытии его в Eclipse и с дальнейшим обновлением проекта на app engine. Можно ли извлечь проект из Google app engine и в каком виде он будет?

Answer (score 2):

На каком языке выполнен проект? Go, Java, Python, PHP?

Например, Java, как правило, разворачивается на Google App Engine в виде стандартной war-директории, в соответствии с [Servlet Specification 2.5](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=154). То есть, в скомпилированном виде. Следовательно, извлекать проект из GAEj толку мало. Хотя это можно сделать с помощью [утилиты из SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application). Лучше взять исходники, чем заниматься декомпиляцией.

Подготовка к работе с проектом GAEj похожа на подготовку веб-приложения Java. Для сборки советую использовать [Gradle c плагином](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin), хотя и [Maven с инструкциями и плагином](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) подойдёт. Дополнительно необходим конфигурационный файл [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig). При разработке используется сервер из комплекта SDK, созданный на базе Jetty.

С помощью указанного плагина для системы сборки можно выполнить ряд действий. Например:

- Запустить локальный сервер
- Развернуть проект на локальном сервере
- Обновить локально развёрнутый проект
- Загрузить проект на сервер Google App Engine
- Скачать развёрнутый проект с сервера Google App Engine
- ...и многое другое.

Кроме того, для отладки необходимо создать удалённую конфигурацию отладчика и передавать локальному серверу при запуске некоторые параметры. При настройке отладчика IDE должна их показать.

Несмотря на то, что существует [плагин для Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse), позволяющий сделать перечисленные выше действия с помощью кнопочек из IDE, я рекомендую использовать команды систем сборки и плагина GAE. Это даст Вам повторяемость процесса сборки на девелоперской машине и на сервере непрерывной интеграции, и на машине другого разработчика.